# Comparing effectiveness of various treatments over control via matched pairs

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

Imagine this experiment: assume that I have two sets of twins.  For the first pair of twins, I keep one as a control, and the second twin I give drug A.  For the second pair of twins, I keep one as a control and I give the second twin drug B.  Now, I want to show that the effectiveness of drug A over control is bigger than the effect of drug B over control.  In each case, I measure a response in each twin like say body temperature.

My goal would be to prove that drug A lowered body temperature more than drug B compared to the control, a single p-value summarizing the experiment for instance.

I replicate the whole experiment three times.  So, for drug A, I have three pairs of numbers, each making a comparison between a pair of twins, one given the drug and one left as a control; and the same for drug B.

How do I go about analyzing an experiment like this?

(For a lot of technical reasons related to my application, I have to work with matched pairs; and I'm not really experimenting on humans.)